# Jslint missing semicolon error

Tags: jquery, jslint

Edited with the entire code: line 17 is now 33.

I ran this code in http://www.javascriptlint.com and it says that there's a missing semicolon on line 33. I added it but it's breaking everything. Can anyone help me to spot the error?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $container = $('.row');

    $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.post',
            columnWidth: 1
        });
    });


    $container.infinitescroll({
        navSelector: '#page-nav',
        nextSelector: '#page-nav a',
        itemSelector: '.post',
        loading: {
            finishedMsg: "No more entries to load.",
            img: "http://static.tumblr.com/7wtblbo/hsDlw78hw/transparent-box.png",
            msgText: "Loading..."
        },
        debug: true,
        bufferPx: 5000,
        errorCallback: function () {
            $('#infscr-loading').animate({
                opacity: 0.8
            }, 2000).fadeOut('normal')
        },  
    },

    function (newElements) {
        var $newElems = $(newElements).css({
            opacity: 0
        });
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function () {
            $newElems.animate({
                opacity: 1
            });
            $container.masonry('appended', $newElems, true);
        });
    });


    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('.row').masonry();
    });


    setTimeout(function () {
        $container.masonry({
            appendedContent: $(newElements)
        });
        /* repair audio players*/
        $('.audio').each(function () {
            var audioID = $(this).attr("id");
            var $audioPost = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/read/json?id=' + audioID,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                timeout: 50000,
                success: function (data) {
                    $audioPost.append('\x3cdiv style=\x22background-color:white;height:30px\x22 class=\x22audio_player\x22\x3e' + data.posts[0]['audio-player'] + '\x3c/div\x3e');
                }
            });
        });


    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

}, 2000).fadeOut('normal')**;**

```
errorCallback: function () { 
    $('#infscr-loading').animate({ 
        opacity: 0.8 
    }, 2000).fadeOut('normal');
}
```

**update:**

```
$container.infinitescroll({ 
    navSelector: '#page-nav', 
    nextSelector: '#page-nav a', 
    itemSelector: '.post', 
    loading: { 
        finishedMsg: "No more entries to load.", 
        img: "http://static.tumblr.com/7wtblbo/hsDlw78hw/transparent-box.png", 
        msgText: "Loading..." 
    }, 
    debug: true, 
    bufferPx: 5000, 
    errorCallback: function () { 
        $('#infscr-loading').animate({ 
            opacity: 0.8 
        }, 2000).fadeOut('normal');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Line 16: solved. It says 'trailing comma is not legal in ECMA-262 object initializers' for line 17 now though.

Comment: Try combining my answer with @Arth's answer.

Comment: Thanks. It's valid code on js lint now but it's breaking the plugin this way. I edited the post with the entire code.

Comment: Nope. Still breaking the plugin. I guess line 28 must stay a , even though it's not valid code.

Comment: @Barbara - considering that I have no reference to "the plugin", I don't think I can help with that.  What I've provided is basic jQuery/JSON syntax.  If you need help with something beyond that, I suggest that you ask a new question.

Comment: Turns out there was some sort of lag between the theme editor and my page. Tested again this morning and it works, thanks!

Comment: @Barbara - np.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the , on line 16  it is erroneous!
As is the , on line 17!

Comment: Done. It still says 'missing semicolon' and 'SyntaxError: missing } after property list' Edit: saw you edited the post. If I remove the , it says missing semicolon.

Comment: Really? it is after the closing }

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes:

- Line 27:  add semicolon
- Line 28: remove comma

*Line numbers are for edited code*